# run-time error 91 when clearing a find/highlight function

Tags: vba, find, runtime-error, highlight

I'm running the following macro to perform a basic 'FindHighlight' function through a database in MS XL 2003

The find function works perfectly, but the issue I have is that when the 'ClearHighlight' is used (before a search is made) then I get Run-time error 91 - 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

I understand that I need to complete a search before using this function, but others using the tool may not - I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this alert coming up? 
(Beginner on VBA!!)

Thank you!

```
Dim FoundRange As Range

Sub FindHighlight()
Dim tempCell As Range, Found As Range, sTxt As String
sTxt = InputBox("Search string")
If sTxt = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set Found = Range("A1")
Set tempCell = Cells.Find(what:=sTxt, After:=Found, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If tempCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox prompt:="Not found", Title:="Finder"
Exit Sub
Else
Set Found = tempCell
Set FoundRange = Found
End If
Do
Set tempCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=Found)
If Found.Row >= tempCell.Row And Found.Column >= tempCell.Column Then Exit Do
Set Found = tempCell
Set FoundRange = Application.Union(FoundRange, Found)
Loop
FoundRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
FoundRange.Font.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub

Sub ClearHighlight()
FoundRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
FoundRange.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If `FoundRange` is not set it's value is `Nothing` so:

```
Sub ClearHighlight()
   if FoundRange is nothing then exit sub

   FoundRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
   FoundRange.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe just add a `MsgBox` like in OP : `If tempCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ...`